# calculating number of days between 2 days tcl

Tags: date, tcl

I am calculating the number of days between two dates(the 2 dates are in seconds). The following gives me the coorect result but it gives me a negative value.

For example -7.0. I am not sure why..

Also can I remove the decimal point and display?

```
        set interval [expr { $start_date - $get_date }]
        set days [expr { floor($interval / (60*60*24)) }]
        puts "Start Date: $start_date <br>"
        puts "Stop Date: $get_date <br>"
        puts "Total number of dates betwen 2 days: $days"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're subtracting the end (assuming that's what `$get_date` is) from the start. Think of it like numbers, where a later date is a bigger number - if you subtract a large number from a small number, you get a negative value, right?

So you probably just want to reverse the arithmetic:

```
set interval [expr { $get_date - $start_date }]
```

I've no idea about the decimal point part, I'm afraid... perhaps (based on [this documentation](http://wiki.tcl.tk/583)) just:

```
set days [expr { int($interval / (60*60*24)) }]
```

EDIT: As noted in comments, some care is required when it comes to "days" between two events. Do you mean elapsed days, 24 hours per day, or "local" days? Are your input values in local time, UTC, or something else? Could you perhaps use a dedicated date/time library to handle this? (I have no idea whether tcl has such a thing, but I'd expect it to.)

You should think *really* carefully about exactly what behaviour you want in what situation, and write tests accordingly.

Comment: Better to use `round` in this case because of DST changes.

Comment: wow foolish of me..is there anyway i can remove the decimal point?

Comment: @DonalFellows: Not necessarily. It depends what the intended results are. If it should only show whole days (but the input could contain times as well) then more work is needed. If both values are UTC, no change is needed. Will edit the answer to explain this a bit further though.

Comment: I took days to mean, well, days. I was also sort of assuming that the `$get_date` and `$start_date` were extracted with Tcl's `clock scan` applied to a partial timestamp (with just the date portion); at that point, the real problem is dealing with DST…

Comment: @DonalFellows: It's possible, certainly. Hard to say for sure - and the actual requirements may suggest that that's not the right approach to start with. Basically I don't think we have enough information to say definitively, and I don't want to give the impression that just using `round` will always give the desired value. There's enough subtlety in date/time computation that a single answer is almost never appropriate for everything :(

Answer (score 3):

Not all days are 86400 seconds long, because of little things like daylight savings time. Because of this, you need to do some rounding in your calculation (and use floating point division):

```
set days [expr {round($interval / double(60*60*24))}]
```

You also usually subtract the start from the end when calculating the length of an interval, not the other way round. Gets the sign right.